# Type '<T>(array: T[], pred: (x: T) => boolean, index: number) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'

Tags: typescript, extension-methods, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create an extension method for Array.

This is what I've created:

```
interface Array<T> {
    moveServiceBranchInArray(): void;
}

Array.prototype.moveServiceBranchInArray = function<T> (array: T[], pred: (x: T) => boolean, index: number): void 
{ 
    const curPos: number = array.findIndex(pred);
    index = Math.max(Math.min(index, array.length - 1), 0);

    if (curPos < 0) {
      return;
    }
    [array[curPos], array[index]] = [array[index], array[curPos]];
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the error

**"Type 
'(array: T[], pred: (x: T) => boolean, index: number) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'."**

as shown in the title.  What gives, help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify function arguments in your interface like this:

```js
interface Array<T> {
    moveServiceBranchInArray(array: T[], pred: (x: T) => boolean, index: number): void;
}

Array.prototype.moveServiceBranchInArray = function<T> (array: T[], pred: (x: T) => boolean, index: number): void 
{ 
    const curPos: number = array.findIndex(pred);
    index = Math.max(Math.min(index, array.length - 1), 0);

    if (curPos < 0) {
      return;
    }
    [array[curPos], array[index]] = [array[index], array[curPos]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your interface has a method that takes no parameter, hence `() => void`, but in the implementation you get some parameters, specifically with the signature `(array: T[], pred: (x: T) => boolean, index: number) => void`.

That is exactly what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Fixing the interface to make it match your implementation should be enough.